# How to properly iterate in an array and display the actual array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This has been a long time question in my mind. If I iterate through an array and I put `return array[i]` it will by default display ONLY the first element.

What is the better way to iterate through an array, display ALL its elements/items?

Below I am working on my function which skips the array[n] and display the whole array expect the nth.

```
function getAllElementsButNth(array, n) {
  for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // array.splice(0, array[n]);
    // return array;
     if (i === n) { 
       continue; 
     }
    return array[i];
  }
}

var output = getAllElementsButNth(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1);
console.log(output); // --> ['a', 'c']
```

I notice that using `console.log` will just display them with new lines. I am referring to displaying the actual array itself. I used return here and it only allows me to display the 'a'.

Any help?

Comment: you are returning the element, so it's fair that it logs "a" only. Either return array.slice, either define a new array and push elements to it. Another possibility is using array.filter

Comment: When your functions reaches to `return array[i]` it will be ended. So the result will be the first element that is not equal to `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate through the array at all, or have a function for this. You just need to do :

`var output = array.splice(index, 1)`.

The `array.splice` method takes two parameters: the first one being the index at which to remove elements, and the second being the number of elements to remove, in your case - 1.

`output` will hold the value of the element that was removed, while the initial array will be spliced and contain all original elements except the one at `index`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `array.filter`:

https://jsfiddle.net/5z09ahrq/

```
function getAllElementsButNth(array, n) {
  return array.filter(function(e, i) {
    return i !== n;
  });
}

var output = getAllElementsButNth(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1);
console.log(output); // --> ['a', 'c']
```

concise and easy to read. Also, logically applies to the problem.

However, it may not be the most efficient solution since it iterates the whole array whatsoever.

So, another possible (more efficient) approach using es6 (since there already are other solutions using slice):

```
function getAllElementsButNth(array, n) {
  return new Array(...array.slice(0, n), ...array.slice(n+1, array.length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Array#slice()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjiyP_V8o_UAhWJKY8KHS2OBbIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fslice&usg=AFQjCNFWe1RAaCBk7jRHuWKDLF0zopmTWg&sig2=MQ09jWtjgBBK22WR3DCfMA) method

```js
function getAllElementsButNth(arr, p) {
  if (p - 1 < arr.length) { // its validate p lesser the array length
    return arr.slice(p - 1)[0];
  }
  
}

console.log(getAllElementsButNth(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1))
console.log(getAllElementsButNth(['a', 'b', 'c'], 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without mutating the original array: `filter`

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

var index = 5;

var r = arr.filter((el, i) => i !== index);

console.log(r)
```